# fill multiple text box based on dropdown selection from the controller asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to develop a web application with asp.net mvc3 I have a view that contains a dropdownlist when the user makes a selection of dropdownlist textbox must be filled in automatically how I can do in that in the controller I want to put the code in my view?

Comment: Sorry i Don't want to put code in the view just in the controller thank you.

Comment: There is no Autopostback property for Dropdown in MVC. One approach I can think of is use JQuery to fill it.

Answer (score 0):

Following JQuery plugin might be useful to you.

http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have HTML markup like this

```
<select id="states">
  <option value="1">MI</option>
  <option value="1">MI</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtCity1" value="" />
<input type="text" id="txtCity2" value="" />
```

This script should fill the data, Assuming you have jQuery loaded to your page.

```
$(function(){
 $("#states").change(function(){
     var itemVal=$(this).val();
     $("#txtCity1").val("Selected item is "+itemVal);
     $("#txtCity2").val("Ann Arbor");
 });
});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/JuAhm/4/

If you are looking for a way to bring data from the server and fill in textboxes, You should make a jQuery ajax call and get data in JSON format and read that JSON and set values to different text boxes. Something like this

```
$(function(){
 $("#states").change(function(){
     var itemVal=$(this).val();

     $.getJSON("Url.Action("GetCities","State")"+"?id=itemVal,function(data){
        if(data.Status=="True")
        {
           //you may set the textbox values here by reading json result here
           //ex :   $("#txtCity2").val(data.Status);
          //If you want to loop thru each items under Cities 
          $.each(data.Cities,function(index,item){
            //  alert(item.Name)
          });
        }
        else
        {
           alert("No data found!");
        }

     });         

 });
});
```

Assuming your controller name is `State` and You have an `HTTPGET` action method called `GetCities` which has a parameter called `id` and  returns `JSON` data in the following format.

```
{
    "Status": "True",
    "Cities": [
               {  "ID": "1", "Name": "Ann Arbor" },
               {  "ID": "2", "Name": "Detroit"}
              ]
}
```

Comment: thank you but the dropdownlist cascading the car registration from a model the text box displaying the rest of information of the car in the same model can you helpe me with this?

Comment: @NasnousaBh: Please be more specific when writing a question. That will give you better answers. See my updated answer(a generic version to get data from server side)